# 'type cast': cannot convert from 'T' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

This is the relevant part of the code. It doesn't allow me to assign `t` to my `arrayStringVal` array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

char arrayStringVal[6][20];
#define printf printDeveloperData

template <typename T>
void printDeveloperData(T t)
{

}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printDeveloperData(T& t, Args... args)
{
    strcpy(arrayStringVal[0], (const char*)t );// gives error here cannot convert from t to const char 
    printDeveloperData(args...);
}

int main()
{
    printf("z%d x%d f%d e%d", 22, 3, 11, 13);
    printf("z%d x%d f%s ", 53, 11, 13.1);
}
```

I expect to find a way to assign value of `t` to the array.

Of course, `t` can be anything, but this is only a relevant part of the code. In the real code, I put some condition before `strcpy()` so it only reaches `strcpy()` if `t` is indeed a `const char *`.

But the compiler (Visual Studio C++) keeps giving me the error that `t` cannot be casted to `const char`.

Without the cast, it gives a different error that `strcpy()` doesn't take `t` as a parameter.

I expect to find a way to use `t` in `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two issues:

1. You didn't `#include <cstring>`, so the compiler (probably) doesn't know what `strcpy` is (depending on the compiler headers, it might get the definition from one of your existing `#include`s).
2. For all but the first of the recursive templated invocations, the value being passed as `t` is an `int` (in one case, a `float`), not a string-like thing of any kind. Be grateful it's refusing to perform the cast, if it actually let you do it, you'd be accessing (almost certainly) unallocated memory at the very bottom of the address range.

A wildly incomplete attempt at resolving this (so everything becomes legal string data to copy from) would be:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
char arrayStringVal[6][20];
#define printf printDeveloperData

template <typename T>
void printDeveloperData(T t)
{

}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printDeveloperData(T& t, Args... args)
{
    std::string tstr;
    if constexpr (std::is_array<T>::value || std::is_same<T, const char*>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
        tstr = t;
    } else {
        tstr = std::to_string(t); 
    }
    strcpy(arrayStringVal[0], tstr.data());// gives error here cannot convert from t to const char 
    printDeveloperData(args...);
}




int main()
{
    printf("z%d x%d f%d e%d", 22, 3, 11, 13);
    printf("z%d x%d f%s ", 53, 11, 13.1);

}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLtSuwwEIb/5ypeFKXVWt0VFbbrguAduJw/siwhndZA25RkLK4ft25P2rjH5fgxMEyZPDOZeVPVtielUn2/rxtVPeaEuXJsdVMuxGdKG58jWe/meNPSmq3U7BZCPUgLaa3c3I3Ff2R1f7m6n56tMrGfU6EbQusPuAjhljqqTEv2VrIUgqluK8kfXRtZE5YL0Rmdf4NHS3AsXoR4@yzcqUuw/U7TFDe2dL90OgQnIzOw0sehMbw5zmezIATYx2zM6gLKNI7pqbWIRka79bj3fLmYzTpZPRJeX7E9cn6MuR9prMKg0tFv2M6tWyxGGGiwYRBcg8Mwb6DK0dfjsQmbdegTcZwh8B@LWdVuov/e6myVjOVpPsgSx9npKUrdkQNZayweyBKUbBrDwy4dWUZhTQ0Gm53twk3fKC2DxnE2vJo3D6CWuom2goe/I9p7Psjx5L3wTgf5XoLpNMF5gsnE@3mc/UA7ePTiH5dOPOnv6vt3VVSydP2J1@VaHR9Prv4C)

Comment: To be clear, that `if constexpr` check is *really* bad; it will treat any array as being "probably convertable to string directly". I'm hoping this isn't for real code, because you shouldn't be using it for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for trying shadowranger, Im using visual studio, it is clang, for dynamic library for android pourpouses, line 21    tstr = std::to_string(t);  do work on others but in visual studio clang it says to_string not a member of std. I did find out a way out using stream but it is fun to see people trying to make it work the way I first tried.